# Fade in and fade out different text in a container at the same time in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const firstTitle = document.querySelector(".first-title");
const secondTitle = document.querySelector(".second-title");

const firstSubtitle = document.querySelector(".first-subtitle");
const secondSubtitle = document.querySelector(".second-subtitle");


window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {

    firstTitle.classList.add('fadeOut');
    secondTitle.classList.add('fadeIn');
    firstSubtitle.classList.add('fadeOut');
    secondSubtitle.classList.add('fadeIn');

  }, 4000);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

h1 span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

p span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear infinite;
}

.fadeOut {
  animation: fadeOut 1s linear infinite;
}


/* Fade In and Fade Out Animation */

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Text Fading</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <section>
        <h1>
          <span class="first-title">Title A</span>
          <span class="second-title">Title B</span>
        </h1>
        <p>
          <span class="first-subtitle">Text A</span>
          <span class="second-subtitle">Text B</span>
        </p>
      </section>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

From my code, I have styled it in such a way that the text in the spans inside the h1 and p tags are at the same level. This is because I want a span to fade in the exact same time the other span is fading out such that it creates a temporary overlap effect. However, I am unable to do that with my present knowledge of CSS and JavaScript.

How do I continuously fade in and fade out the two different spans in h1 and p tags simultaneously in an infinite loop such that they overlap at a point before completely fading in or fading out.

Comment: I'm not I sure I understand your question - the code in the snippet looks like it is doing what you describe?

Comment: It isn't . I want the texts to fade in and out simultaneously infinitely. After 5 seconds, it should do that again. That is, the first span fades out and the second span fades in simultaneously. The second span fade in doesn't have to wait for the first span fade out to complete. They both happen at the same time. After 5 seconds, the second span fades in and the first fades out simultaneously.  This continues in a loop

Comment: They are fading in and out simultaneously infinitely from what I can see, so you need to be a bit clearer in your problem statement - is the only problem that it is fading *too quickly* after the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

```js
let title1 = document.getElementById('first-title');
let subTitle1 = document.getElementById('first-subtitle');
let title2 = document.getElementById('second-title');
let subTitle2 = document.getElementById('second-subtitle');

// Third, create variable so is can check if this element is first element or second element
let checkTimes = true;

function hapyFade() {
setTimeout(function(){ 

// Sixthly,Evry time checkTimes is reverse to aprouch toggle element
  if (checkTimes == true) {
  
  // Seventh, In the first case of variapple, hide the first element and show the second
    title1.style.opacity = subTitle1.style.opacity = 0;
    title2.style.opacity = subTitle2.style.opacity = 1;
// Sixthly too, here reverse variable   
checkTimes = false;
  } else {
  
  // Seventh too, In the second case of variapple, hide the second element and show the first
    title1.style.opacity = subTitle1.style.opacity = 1;
    title2.style.opacity = subTitle2.style.opacity = 0;
    
    // Sixthly too, here reverse variable
    checkTimes = true;
  }
  
  // Fifth, same a function inside setTimeOut so reabeate this each 2 second
  hapyFade();
}, 2000);
}

// Fourth, I created a fuction for hide show elemnt as toggle - after 2 second
hapyFade();
```

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

h1 span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Secondly, Hide the second element so that only the first element is on the square at the start of the page */
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

p span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
h1 span,
p span {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Text Fading</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <section>
        <h1>
        <!-- First, here I used id so I can call it in javascript -->
          <span id="first-title">Title A</span>
          <span id="second-title">Title B</span>
        </h1>
        <p>
          <span id="first-subtitle">Text A</span>
          <span id="second-subtitle">Text B</span>
        </p>
      </section>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: Okay @FluffyKitten i will do, but what is the  mean OP?

Comment: It means "Original Poster" - i.e. the person who posted the question :)